# FIELDQUOTE BULK INSERT quotes aren't being removed from loaded data

Tags: sql-server, bulkinsert

Been trying for a while now to load data correctly into a developer edition of Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-GDR) (KB4505224) - 14.0.2027.2 (X64).

I'm trying to load a .txt file with the format `"col1"~"col2"~"col3" CLCF`, however the FIELDQUOTE operator isn't working as intended. The double quotes remain in the columns.

This is the SQL I am using

```
BULK INSERT [staging].[Data]
FROM 'C:\_data\data.txt'

WITH (
    FIRSTROW = 2,
    FIELDQUOTE = '"',
    FIELDTERMINATOR = '~',
    BATCHSIZE=100000,
    MAXERRORS=2);
```

This works but the resulting table still contains the double quotes in every column. I did try with the field terminator wrapped in double quotes like this `FIELDTERMINATOR = '"~"',` but this leaves the first and last column with a trailing and leading " respectively, which is not ideal.

One thing to add is that `FIELDQUOTE` appears in black text whereas the other lines are in blue, like it's not recongised. I know that FIELDQUOTE is new to 2017, but as you can see, I'm running 2017, albeit developer edition, unless that has something to do with it.

I'm assuming the FIELDTERMINATOR is working correctly and the ROWTERMINATOR is being picked up correctly as the data loads with no errors.

I'm stumped, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked in the end. For some reason, specifying that it is a 'CSV' file, although it's a text file. Not sure why it works, but if anyone knows the answer please do share.

```
BULK INSERT [staging].[Data]
FROM 'C:\_data\data.txt'

WITH (FIRSTROW = 2,
    FIELDTERMINATOR = '~',
FIELDQUOTE = '"',
BATCHSIZE=250000,
FORMAT = 'CSV',
CODEPAGE = '65001',
    MAXERRORS=2);
```